# Select, assign a variable, and link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a language selection that is very simple : French or English. If I want to add more languages, then I should have a select so that it does not take a full screen width !

Here is what I currently have:

```
<div id="language">
Language:
<%= link_to_unless_current "English", locale: "en"%> |
<%= link_to_unless_current "Français", locale: "fr"%>
</div>
```

I can't find the correct syntax to place this in a select box. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `select_tag` [helper](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag).

You might also look at:

[options_for_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select)
and
[select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select)